# Chat Programm with C# via IP-Address. Connecting two Computers in different Networks

Tags: c#, email, networking, connection, chat

I'm writing a Chat Programm for me and my friend in C# and I don't know how to connect my Computer to a Computer in a different Network. The Code Works fine in my Home Network between two Computers but between two different Networks it doesn't work. I know why it doesn't work, I mean it makes sense, I think I have Connect our Routers somehow with the Standard Gateway or something but I can't find anything on the internet that helps me.

Maybe C# is the wrong language for a Chat App but I'm sure its possible somehow. If someone could please tell me how this works in C# or which language would be better for it?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set up socket
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        //get user IP
        textLocalIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
        //textRemoteIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
    }

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //binding Socket
        epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
        socket.Bind(epLocal);

        //connecting to remote IP
        epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
        socket.Connect(epRemote);

        //listeninf the specific port
        buffer = new byte[1500];
        socket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Over the Internet - If A connects to B on port X then B needs to configure their router to open &  forward port X to their internal/private IP and probably also needs to configure the Windows Firewall to allow inbound traffic on port X.  A *may* need to similarly configure Windows Firewall to allow outbound connections on X.

Comment: What Alex says plus: Depending on your ISP, it _may_ be impossible (at least with IPv4). That is: If you are using IPv4 and your ISP provides "DualStack", then you share the public IP with other Customers (NAT outside your router). That means you cannot setup a server. In such case, you can resort to IPv6 or setup a server in the internet that will be reached from both your machines. Another possibility for this case is an IPv4overIPv6 Tunnel. But you'll still need to do some of the things Alex mentioned.